# Problems with decimal separator

Tags: python, decimal, separator

I've latitude/longitude numbers, like: -4726786457893145

but i need a decimal separator, like: -47.26786457893145

I've tried 'format' or 'for' structures but without success. I've even converted to list, then inserted a dot and then convert to float again, but not work for all numbers and i do not know why.
I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Here's my partial code:

```
latitude = []
longitude = []
for i in range(len(data['Latitude'])):
    a = list(str(data['Latitude'][i].replace(',','')))
    a.insert(3,'.')
    str1 = ''.join(a)
    latitude.append(float(str1))

    a = list(str(data['Longitude'][i].replace(',','')))
    a.insert(3,'.')
    str1 = ''.join(a)
    longitude.append(float(str1))
```

Comment: Are all the numbers the same length? You have -4726786457893145

-> -47.26786457893145, what would the number 3.26786457893145 (for example) look like in the original format?

Comment: yes, they have the same lenght because are in a particular location where coordinates have -xx.xxxxxxxx format. That is, all numbers need de decimal separator in 3 position. @Nuclear_Wizard

Comment: The problem is how is the best way to insert a 'dot' in this position.

Comment: Are your numbers really that long? That's giving approximately nanometer-scale precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function which I made... which could be written more clearly... will turn -4726786457893145 into -47.26786457893145.

```
def decimal_add(n):
    if n < 0:
        sign = -1
        int_part = float(str(n)[1:3])
        decimal_part = float(str(n)[3:])/10**(len(str(n))-3)


    else:
        sign = 1
        int_part = float(str(n)[0:2])
        decimal_part = float(str(n)[2:])/10**(len(str(n))-2)
    number = (int_part+decimal_part) * sign
    return number
```

Examples from jupyter notebook:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Davis. it helped a lot! regards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are deleting `,` and than trying to insert `.` into the fixed position. It should be more correct to just replace one to another with `.replace(',','.')`
Than your snippet will look this way (with some simplification):

```
latitude = [lat.replace(',','.') for lat in data['Latitude']]
longitude = [lon.replace(',','.') for lon in data['Longitude']]
```

Comment: Thaks for your contribuition Timofey.